# Select users not in array of pointers

Tags: arrays, parse-platform

Using Parse.com and its Cloud code, I want to fetch users that are not in array of users.

```
...
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
query.notContainedIn("objectId", request.object.get("recipients"));
...
query.find().then(
    function(results) {
        console.log("# of users:" + results.length);
    }, 
    function(error) {
        console.error(error)
    }
);
```

**The constraint `notContainedIn` doesn't seem to work, all users are returned, not just the ones not contained in the recipients array coming as part of the request object.**

The recipients array in REST request is defined like this

```
"recipients":[
{"__type":"Pointer","className":"_User","objectId":"qwerty1234"},
{"__type":"Pointer","className":"_User","objectId":"asdfgh1234"}]
```

The data I get as part of the request is ok, because e.g. `request.object.get("recipients")[0].id` returns the `qwerty1234` value.

**What am I doing wrong here?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking parse to compare the objectId to an array of pointers. This would work fine if the column was a Pointer to a User, but you're using just the ID.

The easy solution is to map or extract the ID from the array of pointers, e.g.

```
// at the top, so you can use the Underscore library
var _ = require('underscore');

// ...

// in your Cloud function
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    // _.pluck() creates an array of a property from each object in the parent array
    var recipientObjectIds = _.pluck(request.object.get('recipients'), 'objectId');
    query.notContainedIn('objectId', recipientObjectIds);
```

Comment: In order to get the objectId's, I had to specify 'id' in the _.pluck